# Async Ajax not working in Safari with redirect

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, safari

I am having problems with an async Ajax call not working in Safari. It works in all other browsers but not Safari. This is only a problem when we have a redirect / link on the button or anchor which is clicked to call the Ajax function.

I have create a really simple example below:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Ajax issue is Safari</title>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.js"></script>
<script>
 $( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#mybutton').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "text",
            async: true,
            url: "dosomething.php",
            error: function(a,b,c){
                alert("Ajax Error");
            },
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);
            },
        });
    });
}); 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="page2.php" id="mybutton">Click here</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Where dosomething.php is

```
<?php 

echo "Success. Click ok to be redirected.";

?>
```

A live version of this example is here: http://visionfactor.com.au/ajax-safari/

Whilst there is a href= the Ajax will always spit an error. As soon as I remove the href it will work. Same goes if I use a button instead of an anchor and redirect with Javascript instead. Same result whilst the redirect is in place.

Now I realise I can put the redirect in the Ajax success callback, however I don't want to do that as it seems unnecessary as it should work the other way in Safari just like all the other browsers. Also in my real world (non simplified) code doing this is quite messy as I have the same class for multiple links / buttons so they all do the same Ajax but then each redirects to a different location. So then I would have to pass through some other value, eg another class, in order to define the relevant redirect specific to that link... like I said messy.

How can I make this really simple code work in Safari?

Thanks,
Nicole

Comment: firefox pops up "Ajax error" quickly then page2 appears - there **is no redirect happening**

Comment: It's entirely possible that safari aborts the default click action because there's an ajax going on. You have to be more explicit in the desired behaviour rather than let the browsers do what they want and hope they're consistent.

Comment: There's an error in dosomething.php. Try `return false;` After ajax call and troubleshoot your code

Comment: So it does in firefox - thanks for pointing that out. Oddly this is not happening with my real world example. I hadn't tested this simple versions in firefox as I just put it together really quickly.

Comment: What is wrong with dosomething.php? What is the error with that file?

Answer (score 0):

try to add `preventDefault` like this :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#mybutton').click(function (event) {

        event.preventDefault(); // stop the click to redirect to the URL in href

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "text",
            async: true,
            url: "dosomething.php",
            error: function(a,b,c){
                alert("Ajax Error");
            },
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);
            },
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi mmm, I'm not sure you have understood my issue. I want it to redirect to the URL and do the ajax async in the background. If I didn't want it to go to the URL then I would remove the URL and the ajax would just work fine.

Comment: I have worked out a solution loosely based on preventing the default event then grabbing the href from the original link and redirecting to that location in the ajax success function. This seems to work however it is a bit messy... I still feel like there should be a better solution but at least this is working.